# Implement an async builder pattern in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, types, future, builder

I want to implement a future for a builder. This can be common for examples such as configuring a request via a builder, then sending it off.

I want to implement `IntoFuture` for a builder but I cannot do this without dynamic dispatch. My gut tells me I should be able to do this without having to allocate additional memory.

For example

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct FooFluentBuilder {
    value: i32,
}

impl FooFluentBuilder {
    fn value(mut self, value: i32) -> Self {
        self.value = value;
        self
    }

    async fn send(self) -> Result<i32, &'static str> {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50)).await;
        Ok(self.value)
    }
}

impl std::future::IntoFuture for FooFluentBuilder {
    type Output = Result<i32, &'static str>;
    type IntoFuture = std::pin::Pin<Box<dyn std::future::Future<Output = Self::Output>>>;

    fn into_future(self) -> Self::IntoFuture {
        Box::pin(self.send())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _response = FooFluentBuilder::default().value(5).send().await;
    let _response = FooFluentBuilder::default().value(5).await;
}
```

In this example, I am converting my Foo request into a dynamic future represented by `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ...>>>`. Ideally I want the type returned by `FooFluentBuilder::send` but that `Future` type is opaque and not representable via Rust.

Are there existing mechanisms, today, to implement `IntoFuture` without dynamic dispatch?

See example above. There I am using a dyn Future, but I want a concrete future. I don't know how I would implement that.

Comment: Not on stable, but why won't you just call `send()` manually?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because it's an extra line I'd like to avoid having users issue. What did you mean by not on stable? Is there a way via nightly?

Comment: Yes, with `type_alias_impl_trait`.

Comment: You can also hand roll `send` implementation. That is create a new type that you can name and implement `Future` for it manually. This will work on stable (and is de facto standard in the ecosystem), but I admit it can be painful.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `Future` manually for a type you create, and then name this type in `<Self as IntoFuture>::IntoFuture`. This works on stable rust today.

```rust
use std::future::{Future, IntoFuture};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

#[derive(Default)]
struct FooFluentBuilder {
    value: i32,
}

impl FooFluentBuilder {
    fn value(mut self, value: i32) -> Self {
        self.value = value;
        self
    }

    fn send(self) -> SendFut {
        SendFut { builder: self }
    }
}

struct SendFut {
    builder: FooFluentBuilder
}

impl Future for SendFut {
    type Output = Result<i32, &'static str>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(self.get_mut().builder.value)) 
    }
}


impl IntoFuture for FooFluentBuilder {
    type Output = <<Self as IntoFuture>::IntoFuture as IntoFuture>::Output;
    type IntoFuture = SendFut;

    fn into_future(self) -> Self::IntoFuture {
        self.send()
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _response = FooFluentBuilder::default().value(5).send().await;
    let _response = FooFluentBuilder::default().value(5).await;
}
```

Comment: this doesn’t quite work because the answer changes ‘send’ from async to sync. If send was sync then the example is trivial because I can return a Ready

Comment: @JinyoungChoi `async` functions are nothing more than normal function that return some type that implements the `Future` trait. The only difference between this examples is that in my solution you can _name_ this type, and by that avoid using dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @JinyoungChoi read [this paragraph](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html#asyncawait) from the Async Book to learn what `async/await` really does to your functions.

Comment: I am aware of the transformation `async` functions undergo, could you help explain how this applies to this example?

As a side question could the answer be modified to support an async call?

Comment: @JinyoungChoi I would love to help, but now I don't understand what you don't understand. I've included `main` function which is the same one as in your original code. Using `FooFluendBuilder` has not changed. You can use `FooFluentBuilder::send` the same way as if it was `async fn send(self) -> ...`. What do you mean by "could the answer be modified to support an async call"?

Comment: first thank you for your time and information. I modified my example above to include a `tokio::time::sleep` to my `FooFluentBuilder::send` function. This represents a network call. Could you explain if your example could work with the new example I posted above?

Comment: Ok. Now I understand he problem. You still _can_ implement this future manually, although it may become quite complex once you create some more complex logic. I'll modify my answer to show it, later once I'll have some time.